# How to get the number of pods that my kubernetes cluster is able to have with prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

In the Rancher I can see the amount of pods I have in the cluster and the total amount I can have.
How can I get this maximum amount of pods that my cluster is able to have with prometheus?

[image: Rancher example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visualise based on these two queries

**Total allocable pods:**

```
sum(kube_node_status_allocatable {resource="pods"})
```

you can also cross-verify the result

```
capacity=$(k get node $(k get node | awk '{if (NR==2) print $1}') -ojsonpath='{.status.capacity.pods}{"\n"}')
$capacity*number-of-nodes
```

[Node Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md)

**Total running pods:**

```
sum(kube_pod_status_ready)
```

cross verification

```
 k get pods -A | wc
```

[pod-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md)

So you can visualise this in Grafana

[image]